# Terraform azapi provider "ChainedTokenCredential authentication failed"

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azapi

I am trying to create a Virtual Machine Image using the Terraform azapi provider. Within the same configuration I'm also using Azurerm, which works fine.

This is how I set up my providers:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~>1.4.0"
  backend "azurerm" {}
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.64.0"
    }
    # Additional providers must be added below
    azapi = {
      source  = "Azure/azapi"
      version = "=1.10.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  subscription_id = <Subscription ID>

  features {}
  skip_provider_registration = "true"
}

provider "azapi" {
  subscription_id   = <Subscription ID>
  use_cli           = true
}
```

This is the resource that I am trying to deploy:

```
resource "azapi_resource" "<Reference-Name>" {
  type      = "Microsoft.VirtualMachineImages/imageTemplates@2022-02-14"
  name      = "<Resource-Name>"
  location  = "westeurope"
  parent_id = <Resource Group id>
  tags      = var.tags
  identity {
    type         = "UserAssigned"
    identity_ids = [<Managed identity id>]
  }
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      buildTimeoutInMinutes = 0
      customize = [
        {
          name        = <script-name>
          type        = "PowerShell"
          runAsSystem = true
          runElevated = true
          scriptUri   = <script URL>
        }
      ]
      distribute = [
        {
          artifactTags      = {}
          runOutputName     = <output-name>
          type              = "SharedImage"
          excludeFromLatest = true
          galleryImageId    = <gallery-id>
          replicationRegions = [
            "westeurope"
          ]
          storageAccountType = "Blob"
        }
      ]
      validate = {
        continueDistributeOnFailure = true
      }
      source = {
        type      = "PlatformImage"
        publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop"
        offer     = "Windows-10"
        sku       = "22h2-avd"
        version   = "latest"
      }
      stagingResourceGroup = <staging RG name>
      vmProfile = {
        osDiskSizeGB = 64
        vmSize = "Standard_B2ms"
        vnetConfig = {
          subnetId = <subnet id>
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

I am using the Azure CLI for authentication. But when I try to apply this I get the following error:

```
│ Error: checking for presence of existing Resource: (ResourceId "/subscriptions/<Subscription ID>/resourceGroups/<RG-name> /providers/Microsoft.VirtualMachineImages/imageTemplates/<Resource-name>" / Api Version "2022-02-14"): ChainedTokenCredential authentication failed
│ GET http://169.254.169.254/metadata/identity/oauth2/token
│ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
│ RESPONSE 403 connecting to 169.254.169.254:80: connecting to 169.254.169.254:80: dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: connectex: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network.
│ ---------------------------
│ connecting to 169.254.169.254:80: connecting to 169.254.169.254:80: dial tcp 169.254.169.254:80: connectex: A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network.
│ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
│ 
│ 
│   with azapi_resource.avd_image,
│   on main.tf line 80, in resource "azapi_resource" "<Resource-name>":
│   80: resource "azapi_resource" "<Resource-name>" {
```

I couldn't find anything online that would explain why only azapi would fail but azurerm would not. I have also tried it for different resources with azapi, and that results in the same error. I have also tried connecting to different networks. What could be my mistake here?

Comment: Please share the terraform configuration you tried.

Comment: @VinayB I added the code that I used for the resource

Comment: did you resolve this, i am having the same issue.  It used to work about 6 months ago.  but now for places where i am using azapi, i cam getting this ChaineTokenCredential Authentication failure

Comment: @mike01010 Hi, I think it was solved by first setting up a point-to-site VPN to your Azure environment before running your code. That should solve it. 

I thought it had something to do with private DNS resolving, not sure tho anymore

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to create a Virtual Machine Image using the Terraform azapi provider and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The error you are encountering, "ChainedTokenCredential authentication failed", typically indicates an issue with Azure CLI authentication or Managed Identity configuration.

Since you're using Azure CLI for authentication (`use_cli = true` in the `azapi` provider configuration), ensure that you are logged in with the Azure CLI and have the correct permissions

Run `az login` to authenticate your Azure CLI session, and verify with `az account show` that you are logged in to the correct account with necessary permissions.

For [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/install-azure-cli) you can use this path to re-install the Azure CLI
if youre using in local.

[image]

**My demo terraform configuration:**

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "= 3.84.0"
    }
    azapi = {
      source  = "Azure/azapi"
      version = "= 1.10.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "your subscription ID"
  skip_provider_registration = "true"
}


provider "azapi" {
  subscription_id = "Your subscription ID"
  use_cli         = true
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example_rg" {
  name     = "demorg-vk"
  location = "east us"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example_vnet" {
  name                = "vkvnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example_rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example_rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example_subnet" {
  name                 = "vksnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example_rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example_vnet.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_user_assigned_identity" "example" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example_rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example_rg.location
  name                = "demovk-identity"
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example_nic" {
  name                = "demovkNIC"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example_rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example_rg.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example_subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azapi_resource" "vm" {
  type      = "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines@2022-03-01"
  name      = "demoVM"
  location  = "east us"
  parent_id = azurerm_resource_group.example_rg.id
  depends_on = [azurerm_network_interface.example_nic]
  body = jsonencode({
    properties = {
      hardwareProfile = {
        vmSize = "Standard_B8ms"
      },
      storageProfile = {
        imageReference = {
          publisher = "Canonical"
          offer     = "UbuntuServer"
          sku       = "18.04-LTS"
          version   = "latest"
        },
        osDisk = {
          createOption = "FromImage"
          caching             = "ReadWrite"
          managedDisk = {
            storageAccountType = "Standard_LRS"
          }
           diskSizeGB          = 30 
        }
      },
      osProfile = {
        computerName  = "demovkVM"
        adminUsername = "adminuser"
        adminPassword = "YouPassword123!" // Replace with a secure password
      },
      networkProfile = {
        networkInterfaces = [
          {
            id = azurerm_network_interface.example_nic.id,
            properties = {
              primary = true
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      // Additional properties as required
    },
    identity = {
      type = "SystemAssigned"
    }
  })
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: what strange is this used to work without me needing to explicitly set a subscription id or use_cli, i just do an 'az login',the browsers pops up, i login and im good to go.  Something must have changed in the last few months - i am still not able to resolve my issue with your suggestions...

Comment: ok thanks much - the links you provided answered how to add the Reader roll and assign to users/app.  I feel still this must be new cause i can understand how it worked in the past.  One last question - i would like to assign these RBAC roles and user/app associations via terraform when im creating my core infrastructure. is that doable? do u have docs on that?

Comment: You can check with this https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/role_assignment @mike01010 for RBAC role assignment using terraform